# Open extension on click from a website. Like metamask

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How do I make my extension popup window come up when I click on a button from another website?

I tried using a background script, but it's not working. Here's what I've done:

1. Created a `manifest.json` file with the necessary permissions and background script.
2. Added a content script to listen for the button click event.
3. Created a `popup.html` file for the popup window content.

However, the popup window is not appearing when I click the button on the other website. Can someone please help me identify what I might be doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Can someone please post the entire source code of their extension? Thank you!